# Limiting geocoding calls in a Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-geocoder, google-geocoding-api

I'm using [this script](http://www.digital-geography.com/geocoding-google-spreadsheets-the-simpler-way/) to geocode an address column in a Google Spreadsheet. It creates a function getLatLon that takes in the value from the address column. Even though I only have 190 rows, I'm quickly reaching the daily geocoding API limit of 2,500. I think this is because the script runs every time the sheet is loaded.

I want to make the script run only if an address hasn't been geocoded yet. For this, I tried accessing the value of the cell with the formula to see if it's blank. If so, run the geocoder. But it's making all my cells, even the geocoded ones, come up blank instead.

Here's my code. I'm not sure if I'm using getValue() correctly (it returns an empty string if no value), or if the fact that my cell has a formula makes the value non-blank.

How else can you test for a blank value in a cell with a formula?

```
function getLatLon(address) {
  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var cell = sh.getActiveCell();
  var value = cell.getValue();

  if (address == '') {
    Logger.log("Must provide an address");
    return;
  }


  if (value == '' ) {

    var geocoder = Maps.newGeocoder();
    var location;
    location = geocoder.geocode(address);
    Utilities.sleep(2000);
// Only change cells if geocoder seems to have gotten a
// valid response.
    if (location.status == 'OK') {
      lat = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lat"];
      lng = location["results"][0]["geometry"]["location"]["lng"];
      return lat + "," + lng

    } 
  }   
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can move geocoded rows to another sheet. Always keep clear data for script.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but with copy -> paste values only. Is that what you mean by clear data? And is there a way to automate this with a script?